# USB device connection on windows triggered 2 times

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, usb, qt5

I'm pretty new to the window programming.
I'm implementing a tray in QT5 that is showing a message when a specific device is connected/disconnected from the PC.
I've created my message-only window, for receiving the disconnect/connect of my USB device. All ok until here, I'm receiving the message but twice for each plugging/unplugging the cable of the device in/from the PC.(don't think windows 10 is so generous in sending it 2 times)

My question: Why is this happening, shouldn't it be only once ?

**This one is already answered, as the device is appearing as HID and USB with the same PID/VID as it was programmed like this.

Here is the code:

```
GUID InterfaceClassGuid = { 0x745a17a0, 0x74d3, 0x11d0, { 0xb6, 0xfe, 0x00, 0xa0, 0xc9, 0x0f, 0x57, 0xda } };

// Registration method

void usbMessage::RegisterNotification()
{
    // Set GUID filter data
    if (usbCNCMsg != nullptr) {
        _pDevIF = (DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE *)malloc(sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE));
        memset(_pDevIF, 0, sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE));
        _pDevIF->dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);

        _pDevIF->dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
        _pDevIF->dbcc_classguid = InterfaceClassGuid;

        // Register for notifications
        _hNotifyDev = RegisterDeviceNotification(this->GetSafeHwnd(), _pDevIF, DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES);
        if (!_hNotifyDev) {
            AfxMessageBox(CString("Can't register device notification: ")
                + _com_error(GetLastError()).ErrorMessage(), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "There was no connection msg Obj passed. MFC msg queue not enabled.";
    }
}


bool usbMessage::matchVidPid(QString dbcc_name)
{
    QString devicePid;
    QString deviceVid;

    int indx = dbcc_name.indexOf("#");
    int indx2 = dbcc_name.indexOf("&");
    deviceVid = dbcc_name.mid(indx  + 1, PID_VID_LENGTH);
    devicePid = dbcc_name.mid(indx2 + 1, PID_VID_LENGTH);

    if (deviceVid == VID_STRNG &&
        devicePid == PID_STRNG) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


LRESULT usbMessage::OnMyDeviceChange(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE pDevInf;

    if (DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL == wParam || DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE == wParam) {
        PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR pHdr = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR)lParam;
        switch (pHdr->dbch_devicetype) {
        case DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE:
            pDevInf = (PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)pHdr;
            if (matchVidPid(QString::fromWCharArray(pDevInf->dbcc_name))) {
                if (DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL == wParam) {                    
                    this->usbCNCMsg->sendMessageConnected(trayMsgHelper::getDeviceConnectedMsg());
                }

                if (DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE == wParam) {
                    this->usbCNCMsg->sendMessageDisconnected(trayMsgHelper::getDeviceDisconnectedMsg());
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried older versions of windows?

Comment: It has to support windows 10, 8.1 and 8.